# Set the padding/margin to the top activity/fragment layout container in theme?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

In my app I wanted to apply padding to all my screen top level container  from the theme.

example :

here is the layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the app theme.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@drawable/window_frame</item>
    </style>
```

I can apply padding using `android:padding` to the parent container  RelativeLayout. But I don't want like this as I need to specify the same in each layout file, I wanted to define that in theme - AppTheme.

Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: create a layout with padding and reuse it where ever you want http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: I am asking about the reusable layouts. Its about theme.

Answer (score 2):

why you need to code extra using style?

You can set padding directly inside res/values/dimens.xml,it would be much easier. and whenever you need to increase or decrease the values you just need to change at single place for every activity

e.g. 
in dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="my_activity_padding">5dp</dimen>
```

and then in activity layout:

```
android:padding="@dimen/activity_padding"
```

Comment: I am using this soln before posting the question. It is good to put those dimension in dimens.xml  file.

Answer (score 1):

The theme is not the solution since it will add padding to all view hierarchy under your layout. (your RelativeLayout as well as the EditText.

Use @Karan solution

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">25dp</item>
    </style>
```

use android:paddingtop in your style

Comment: This doesn't work. it adds padding to the window. my question is about parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your main Theme `<item name="android:padding">50dp</item>` which was used in Manifest.xml `android:theme="@style/AppTheme">` it will affect all layouts which was use this theme.